# Replayability of all messages(Failed/Successfully Processed) via Azure Service Bus

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

We are using Azure Service Bus for asynchronous message processing and one of the requirement is to be able to allow message replay/re-submission regardless of whether it was failed or processed successfully. Generally, poison messages are moved to dead letter queue and successfully messages are marked as 'complete' but I was wondering if someone ran into a similar situation and can provide guidance.

I have looked into 'Auto-forwarding', topic/subscriptions(primary & backup) but lack support of either queue to multiple queue auto-forwarding or moving message from one subscription to another subscription. Few pointers to consider

1. Replay-ability (Manual) should be easily supported by existing tools like Service Bus Explorer or similar offering
2. Ability to filter messages for support staff to easily triage

Comment: See the [reply](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/655#issuecomment-1430816358) to the issue you've raised. I'll also expand here.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Service Bus doesn't provide an option to "replay" messages. That's by design. Replaying messages is a business requirement, not a service feature. As such, you'd have to build it.

If you're looking for something that is log-based, where you can replay messages for the consumer, then ASB is not the service to use. A better service for that would be [Event Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-about) (think Kafka).

Regarding the request to be able to filter messages for support staff to triage efficiently. This is where you shouldn't be using a messaging service. Instead, push the data into a database and query as your heart desires. ASB is not a database. It's not designed for querying. It's a messaging service.